# How to display values from array in email template in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I have a custom module. Which should send some data to customer. Sample data:

```
$log[] = array('pid' => '1000', 'price' => '0.00');
$this->sendMail($log);
```

And my senMail function:

```
public function sendMail($mailMessage) {
        $id_lang = (int) $this->context->language->id;
        $iso_lang = Language::getIsoById($id_lang);

        if (!is_dir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/mails/' . Tools::strtolower($iso_lang))) {
            $id_lang = Language::getIdByIso('pl');
        }

        Mail::Send(
                $id_lang,
 'notification',
 Mail::l('Notification from Hurto module', (int) $this->context->language->id),
 array('{message}' => Tools::nl2br($mailMessage)),
 Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL'),
 null,
 null,
 null,
 null,
 null,
 _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->name . '/mails/'
        );
    }
```

Mail is send but the {message} is not display all data from array. In mail I have only one value - 1000. There is one more thing. How to display all data from array ?

Thanks

---edit

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [pid] => 1000 [price] => 0.00 ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are passing an array to Tools::nl2br which should only be used on a string.

You have 2 options to do what you want. Either format the message before the Mail::Send (but cannot have different aspect depending on the theme) or pass the array to smarty and do it in the tpl.

Option 1:

```
public function sendMail($mailMessage) {
    $id_lang = (int) $this->context->language->id;
    $iso_lang = Language::getIsoById($id_lang);

    if (!is_dir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/mails/' . Tools::strtolower($iso_lang))) {
        $id_lang = Language::getIdByIso('pl');
    }

    $message = "";
    foreach($mailMessage as $m){
        $message .= "pid {$m['pid']} price {$m['price']}".PHP_EOL;
    }

    Mail::Send(
            $id_lang,
            'notification',
            Mail::l('Notification from Hurto module', (int) $this->context->language->id),
            array('{message}' => Tools::nl2br($message)),
            Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL'),
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->name . '/mails/'
        );
}
```

Option 2:

```
public function sendMail($mailMessage) {
    $id_lang = (int) $this->context->language->id;
    $iso_lang = Language::getIsoById($id_lang);

    if (!is_dir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/mails/' . Tools::strtolower($iso_lang))) {
        $id_lang = Language::getIdByIso('pl');
    }

    Mail::Send(
            $id_lang,
            'notification',
            Mail::l('Notification from Hurto module', (int) $this->context->language->id),
            array('{message}' => $mailMessage),
            Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL'),
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->name . '/mails/'
        );
}
```

And in the tpl:

```
{foreach from=$message item=m}
    {$m['pid']} - {$m['price']} <br />
{/foreach}
```